# Apply conditional formatting from one cell to multiple other cells containing same text

Tags: google-sheets

So this is a bit trickier than the title makes it sound.

**Here's my spreadsheet I'm working with:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19uU5YnpihBD3Gg_q3KlFx8w7D3--W_wgIeCkTiC2vO0/edit?usp=sharing

**What I currently have:**

You can see I have a team name list in column M as well as a team color option in column N. When the team color next to the team name is selected, it applies the correct fill color to that team name. Now, these team names can be updated at any time and the team name updates in the standings column as well.

**What I am trying to do:**

When the colors are applied to the team name in column M, I'd like those same colors to also be applied to every cell that contains the exact same team name throughout the sheet.

**How I would logically go about this:**

Get color from N4 dropdown, set adjacent cell (M4) to correct color, get text from M4, apply same background color to every cell containing exact text.

I just don't know how to go about creating this formula. Or would this require a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering just the rule for `Yellow` (others would be equivalent) please try:

```
=or(A1="Yellow",A1=index($M:$M,match("Yellow",$N:$N,0)))
```

with the Apply to range set to A:T.